# How to remove duplicate values from Array Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

How can I remove duplicate values from my array list in Coldfusion.

Currently I have the following that displays the reason a user goes to the hospital:

```
<cfset ReasonforVisit = "#HospitalVisits2.Reason_For_Visit#">
    <cfset counter1 = 1>
    <cfif len(ReasonforVisit)>
      <cfloop query="HospitalVisits2">  
        <cfoutput>
            &nbsp;#HospitalVisits2.Reason_For_Visit#<cfif counter1 LT HospitalVisits2.recordcount>,</cfif>  <cfset counter1++>
        </cfoutput>
      </cfloop></cfif>
```

The issue with this approach it does not take in consideration dupes in the columns.

I have done the following to store the results of the columns in a array and check if dupes but is not working. What am i doing wrong?

```
<cfset ReasonforVisit = "#HospitalVisits2.Reason_For_Visit#">
<cfset ReasonList = ArrayNew(ReasonforVisit)>

    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arraylen(ReasonList)#">
            <cfset currReasonList = ReasonList[i]>
            <cfset nextReasonList = ReasonList[i+1]>
            <cfif currReasonList NEQ nextReasonList>
                <cfset newReasonList = ArrayNew(newcurrReasonList)>
            <cfelse>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
<cfoutput>#newReasonList#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Are there other columns in the db query? If not, you could just use `SELECT DISTINCT Reason_For_Visit ...`

Comment: Well. The first argument of ArrayNew(), accepts an integer, representing the dimension. It looks like you have passed a string as this arg.

Comment: If your values are short, you could convert the array to list and use ListRemoveDuplicates() & then convert it back again to an array.

Comment: What is the vue of "Reason_For_Visit"? As Charles pointed out, the code above wouldn't work with strings like "Broken Arm" because ArrayNew() expects a numeric value indicating the number of dimensions, like ArrayNew(2) creates a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: It would help to have more context about the query and output. Is this related to previous question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374642/how-to-display-distinct-values-in-cfoutput? Specifically are you trying to create a list of reasons for a certain grouping - like per person?

Comment: @Ageax: It has text like "Broken Arm"

Comment: @user9808783 - Is it part of a larger output - like on your other thread? If so, I'd recommend using structures - as you loop - then using StructKeyList to create the csv list. Unlike array, structures are naturally unique. Arrays are better suited when you need to maintain the order of something.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Lucee feature request. Perhaps you can use the examples on this page:

https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-442

```
<cfscript>
s = "a string";
i = 42;
f = pi();
st1 = {key1="value1"};
st1bis = {key1="value1"};
st1ref = st1;
st2 = {key2="value2"};
a1 = [1];
a1bis = [1];
a1ref = a1;
a2 = [2];

base = [s,i,f,st1,st1bis,st1ref,st2,a1,a1bis,a1ref,a2,s,i,f,st1,st1bis,st1ref,st2,a1,a1bis,a1ref,a2];

function arrayRemoveDuplicates(array){
    return array.reduce(function(deduped, el){
        return deduped.find(el) ? deduped : deduped.append(el);
    }, []);
}

writeDump(var=base, label="original")
writeDump(var=arrayRemoveDuplicates(base), label="deduped")
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Not sure why someone voted me down on this answer... for those who don't know, Lucee is open source ColdFusion, and the example I posted, which was taken from the Lucee feature request works.

Comment: I will give you a 1 back for using an example from Adam Cameron. :-)  This answer includes a lot of setup code to demonstrate a final function with closures, but it should be easy to modify to output a comma-delimited list.

Comment: @Shawn, not sure what you're talking about regarding setup. This is out of the box... there's no setup, unless of course you are using an old version of CF that does not support closures. The question didn't specify a required version. You surely did go above and beyond with your answer!

Comment: @Redtopia - I think he just meant the variable initialization ("s", "f", "i", etc...) could be simplified, to make it clearer to someone new to the language. For this specific case it just needs a single array, like:  https://trycf.com/gist/2175cf7e8d93c39d678e88d0ee3a533a/lucee5?theme=monokai  Still, a perfectly good idea for deduping an array, so no idea why it was down voted.

Comment: @Redtopia Sorry, I meant that your code sets up several variables for the function test. The only thing that really matters is the function. It does a good job of demonstrating what exactly the code will do given different types of inputs. I'm guessing that you may have received a downvote because someone didn't understand what the code was doing, and then your answer told the user how to get to the answer instead of just giving them the answer. You even told them this is a place to start. It's annoying when I get downvoted on a correct answer, but sometimes it is what it is. :-/

Comment: And frankly, this is precisely one of the things closures excel at. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I may be misinterpreting what you're really looking for, and if so, I'll change my answer. Based on what you've shown us, you don't want to remove a value from an array. You want to output a comma-delimited list of `Reason_For_Visit` with any duplicates removed, correct?

ColdFusion query objects are pretty easy to work with, and they've been one of the most powerful features of CF since very early in the language's life.

ColdFusion query objects already have a lot of properties of arrays and structures, and many of the same functionalities and behaviors of those complex datatypes can be applied back to cfquery objects.

What you're asking for can essentially be done in a single line (containing a few functions).

```
newReasonList = listChangeDelims( 
    listRemoveDuplicates( 
        valuelist(HospitalVisits2.Reason_For_Visit, "|")
        ,"|"
        ,true 
    )
    ,", "
    ,"|"
    ,false 
) ;
```

I know that comes out as multiple lines, but I formatted that way to make it clearer and because I hate scrolling across the page. :-)

To take a look at what we are doing:

Our query object is the `Reason_For_Visit` column of the `HospitalVisits2` query. One of the oldest CF functions for working with queries is `valueList()`. It will essentially take the values from a query column (`HospitalVisits2.Reason_For_Visit`) and turn that array-ish thing into a delimited list of values for that column (https://cfdocs.org/valuelist). It can take an optional `delimiter` argument that allows us to change the delimiter of our list. I chose to change default value of `,` to a `|` character, so that if any of our items has a comma, it won't later accidentally be interpreted in the list.

Now that we've got a `|`-delimited list of `Reason_For_Visit`, we can use a List Function on that list to get rid of the dupes. That function is very cleverly named `listRemoveDuplicates()` (https://cfdocs.org/listremoveduplicates). It can take two optional arguments: the defined delimiter of the list, and a boolean of whether or not to ignore the case of the strings in the list. We give it the delimiter we set in `valueList()` and tell it to ignore case of duplicates, and we have a de-duped list.

Now we just need to change the delimiters in our string so that they aren't `|`. Fortunately, Coldfusion has another cleverly-named List Function, `listChangeDelims()` (https://cfdocs.org/listchangedelims). This function takes our list and an argument for the new delimiter we want. Default is a comma. It also takes two optional arguments. We can specify what our current delimiter is (`|`) and we can tell it that we want to include empty values. Here, we probably don't want those empties. That could give us a list like `Thing1, Thing2,,Thing4`.

`valueList()` is super old, and will be pretty much usable in any version of ColdFusion or even a semi-compatible CFML parser. `listRemoveDuplicates()` and `listChangeDelims()` were added in CF10 and are available in Lucee 4.5+. And apparently TryCF indicates that it will still run in Railo 4.2. If you're using anything older than that, it will be slightly trickier and probably slower to remove those dupes.

I created an example at https://trycf.com/gist/8e3107959cc051dd264b850bbeae88e3/acf?theme=monokai. You can also see that these functions will handle a query that is empty, a query with just one element and a query with just one empty element. You won't get stray commas.

There are other ways to do this, and I'm not sure how it would scale with an extremely large list, but this will work pretty quickly. And this method would be pretty easy to modify if you needed to iterate over multiple patients to output their reasons. With newer versions of CF, there are closures and other things that can be used to make this a bit faster.

================================================

***EDIT: MODIFIED FOR CFMX***

https://trycf.com/gist/91bc66f0fd0b7597e7a4652e9d255e41/acf?theme=monokai

I should note that I don't currently have a way to test for something as old as CFMX, so I am purely going off of memory. I can't remember if you could set delimiters in `valueList()` and `structKeyList()` in CFMX. They can be removed, and you'll still get a comma-delimited list. It just won't have the extra space after the comma. You'll have to test.

Essentially, you can loop through your query and build a struct (that will not insert duplicate keys by nature), <s>but I was seeing a leading comma there when I tried to output the struct key list, which required additional processing to remove that comma</s>. So I think the cleaner way may be able to loop through the value list instead of loop through the query. I know that looping through a list will be slower than looping over a query, but I'm not sure how much impact this will have at your scale. I went with:

```
<!--- create the struct --->
<cfset newReasonStruct = StructNew() />

<!--- CF Structs will overwrite duplicate keys. ---> 
<!--- NOTE: I can't remember if delimiters were valid arguments for valuelist() in CFMX --->
<cfloop index="VisitReason" list="#valuelist(HospitalVisits2.Reason_For_Visit, "|")#" delimiters="|">
    <cfif len(trim(Reason_For_Visit))> <!--- Don't add empties. --->
        <cfset newReasonStruct[VisitReason] = "" > 
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<!--- Set a variable for our new list. --->
<cfset newReasonList = StructKeyList(newReasonStruct,", ") >

This is our main query (with valuelist()): <cfoutput>#newReasonList#</cfoutput>
```

**EDIT 2:** See my strikeout above. I wasn't thinking. The leading comma was being caused by an empty element in the query loop. This caused a "key" value to be an empty string, which was then getting sorted to the beginning of my output string. The `valueList()` list loop method was filtering that empty element out, but the query loop wasn't. So the extra processing to trim the leading comma could simply be done by changing to a query loop and not adding a "key" to the struct if it was empty. However, this changes from one set of `cfif/right()` functions at the end to a `len(trim())` function for every loop in the query. Again, depending on your data, one function may be more performant than the other. Though this feels a little like micro-optimization.

```
<!--- CF Structs will overwrite duplicate keys. ---> 
<cfloop query="HospitalVisits2">
    <cfif len(trim(Reason_For_Visit))> <!--- Don't add empties. --->
      <cfset newReasonStruct[Reason_For_Visit] = "" > 
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

https://trycf.com/gist/169e9e0a592bf88aac462cc3a6e0d2c6/acf?theme=monokai

Comment: I did look into listRemoveDuplicates function. Unfortunately, the current version I am using is extremely old. It is coldfusion MSX or something like that.

Comment: @user9808783 If you are using ColdFusion MX, especially if it involves anything involving medical topics, then you are in desperate need of pushing to upgrade ColdFusion. And if money is an issue, then maybe go with Lucee. But you are setting yourself up for a _LOT_ of problems running that version. And I would guess that if you are running a version that old, the server itself is likely very far out of life. I hate sounding like an alarmist, but seeing anyone still actively using CFMX sets off all sorts of red flags and flashing lights. That said, see my answer update.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do agree and I have mentioned it to my current employer but is resistant to move up currently

Comment: @user9808783 Let me know if my recommended changes for MX work. And I understand you're in a tough spot re: CFMX. If your boss needs a valid reason to be less resistant to upgrade, remind your boss that it's not difficult for CFMX issues to run afoul of HIPAA. :-S Good luck.

Comment: Question: how does the CF Structs overwrite duplicate keys? Reason I am asking I am still seeing duplicate values. Example "NAUSEA, NAUSEA, MED EVAL, MED EVAL", etc

Comment: Honestly, if it's medical information I absolutely *would* be an alarmist and tell them "Upgrading is probably cheaper all around than fines, having to inform customers of a breach and the loss of revenue when the server gets hacked". :-) The old versions have a lot of security holes..

Comment: @user9808783 - Structures are naturally unique, so either the string values are actually different (like leading/trailing spaces) or possibly it has something to do with how you're applying the code.

Comment: @Shawn: I see. I followed the steps that you provided. Let me see what I am doing wrong then

Comment: @user9808783 - You can also use trycf.com to share runnable examples. Here's a starter example, with dummy data:  https://trycf.com/gist/011f0d38285dbf5f937e8260039abab4/acf11?theme=monokai

Comment: @Ageax Don't forget that, with HIPAA, it's not just reputation damage, lost revenue and steep fines, there's also potential jail time and further litigation by those whose data was stolen. If you let the wrong people access certain data, it can be a bit costly. And running extremely old software significantly increases that risk. Especially a system that any script kiddie with Metasploit and Google can do with as they please.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly faster and more modern:

```
public array function arrayUnique(required array sourceArray){
  var source = arguments.sourceArray;
  return source.filter((item, index) => source.find(arguments.item) == arguments.index);
}
```